# Bitbucket to Google App Engine Deployment failed - ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/app.yaml] does not exist

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy a spring boot microservices application to Google App Engine from Bitbucket Pipelines. I am getting this below error after commiting the code,

```
INFO: Setting up environment.
echo "${KEY_FILE}" | base64 -d >> /tmp/key-file.json  
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/key-file.json --quiet --verbosity=warning  
Activated service account credentials for: [testproject-iamserviceaccoun@testproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com]  
gcloud config set project testproject --quiet --verbosity=warning  
Updated property [core/project].  

> *INFO: Starting deployment to GCP app engine...*  
gcloud app --quiet deploy 'app.yaml' --verbosity=warning  
**ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/app.yaml] does not exist.  
✖ Deployment failed.**
```

Please help me to solve this issue. Build Tool used is Maven.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
pipelines:
  default:
     - step: 
        name: Deploy to Google cloud
        deployment: test
        script: 
          - pipe: atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:0.7.3
            variables: 
              KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE
              PROJECT: 'testproject'
```

src/main/appengine/app.yaml:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify DEPLOYABLES in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml, pointing to the path of your app.yaml file.

```
pipelines:
  default:
     - step: 
        name: Deploy to Google cloud
        deployment: test
        script: 
          - pipe: atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:0.7.3
            variables: 
              KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE
                  PROJECT: 'testproject'
                  DEPLOYABLES: src/main/appengine/app.yaml
```

Reference: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy/src/master/

Comment: It's kinda strange that the "official" appengine-maven example contains ```DEPLOYABLES: 'target/appengine-staging/app.yaml'``` (which in fact contains the app.yaml file after you build the project), but it doesn't find the file. Makes more sense to define the target folder as an artifact and expect appengine to start from there. I'll try from src, thanks